# Blender Arrow when rendering

Tags: rendering, render-passes

When I try to render some scene for some reason I can see arrows around object, how can make them not to show at render?
[image]

Comment: blender does not just randomly add arrows to your scene. There must be arrow objects in there somewhere. Find them and either delete, or hide for rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your arrows objects? If so, uncheck their camera icon in the Outliner. 
If you want to render to OpenGL make sure to mark "Only Render" under /Display in the 3D-view Properties window, too.